# List index out of range when using iloc

Tags: python, loops, indexoutofboundsexception

```
Tweets_df['question_user_id'] = 0
Tweets_df['question'] = 0
for i in range(Tweets_df.shape[0]): # Suppose Tweets_df is a dataframe with 100 rows
    if Tweets_df['main tweet (*** means no)'].iloc[i] == "***":
        if len(Tweets_df['reply_to'].iloc[i]) != 1:
            continue
        else:
            Tweets_df['question_user_id'].iloc[i] = Tweets_df['reply_to'].iloc[i][1]['username']
```

There is an IndexError: list index out of range, when the interpreter got to the last sentence of the codes. Does anyone know why there is such an error? I don't see the error because I consider the range(Tweets_df.shape[0]) will have [0,1,...,99] and the iloc corresponds from [0,1,...,99] as well... Thank you.

Comment: The `i` looks correct. Is `iloc[i][1]['username']` causing the issue?

Comment: How about trying adding a `,` while using `iloc` like this

`if len(Tweets_df['reply_to'].iloc[i, ]) != 1:`

Answer (score 0):

change last line of code to:

```
Tweets_df['question_user_id'].iloc[i] = Tweets_df['reply_to'].iloc[i][0]['username']
```

as the else part gets executed only when the length of Tweets_df['reply_to'] is 1 and you were trying to access the 'username' of second element(which does not exist) by using Tweets_df['reply_to'].iloc[i][1]['username'].